# Transfer text file items with degree symbol to datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I am trying to input items in datagridview using text file.

I have below code to transfer the values of a csv file to my datagridview.

```
private void TransfertoDataGridView()
{
    try
    {
        string SelectedReport = ReportsFilename;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(SelectedReport);
        string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (string c in columnnames)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(c);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        string newline;
        while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (newline != "")
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                string[] values = newline.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dr[i] = values[i];
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        file.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    }

}
```

Below is how my csv file looks like,

Column D has items with degree symbol.

[image]

And when I run the code, it transfers all the cell values but replaces the degree symbol with question mark "?".

[image: Degree Sign]

I need expert help on how I can input the degree symbol to the datagridview.

Thank you very much in advanced for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
string str = "this is my string with a � sign like this.";
str = str.Replace('�', '°');
```

As a result:

```
this is my string with a ° sign like this.
```

If String like `�` then it will replace a `°` sign.

Any symbol I guess you can do it with a `replace` function.

Comment: Thanks red. Works like charm. How did you get the string with question mark. I've just copy pasted it in my code.

Comment: Trying to simulate your problem.. before it posted and well done.

Comment: Can't see � in charmap.